# How to define font in FPDF?

Tags: php, drupal, fpdf

I am trying to make a writable .PDF document for my Drupal-site. I am a newbie at Drupal so I am attaching the code as a part of the body. Now I cannot get it load the fonts. I get the following error: **

> FPDF error: Could not include font definition file

**

I have tried modifying the folder privileges and defining the path in the following way:

```
define('php', 'module', 'resources/php/fpdf/font/courier.php');
module_load_include('php', 'module', 'resources/php/fpdf/fpdf');
```

Could someone spare 5 minutes and tell me how to do it. It would mean a lot to me,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the path to the fpdf font directory is done like this:

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'resources/php/fpdf/font/');
```

the path must be relative to the location of your php code